# preloading images from specific folder

Tags: jquery

I would like to use my own slideshow instead of using some plugin for my joomla templates. Thus I need to have preload images as in plugins the images are taken from folder. So my question is that how to create an array from the specific folder for eg. `my-template/bg` taking all the images and that last uploaded image should be at the last of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion I hacked together without testing :-)

Inside your template:

```
<script>var imgObj = <?php echo $this->getDirectory('images');  ?></script>
```

Inside your jQuery's document ready block

```
// load images into DOM and wait for load event
if (typeof window.imgObj === 'object') {

      $(window.imgObj).each(function (index) {
         var url = window.imgObj[index],
             image = $('<img src="' + url + '" />');

      //for old non webkit-opera you need to do a hack like
      image.appendTo('body').remove();

      image.on('load', function () {
         //do stuff with the image once loaded
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brifly:

jQuery use Ajax to call PHP script which get filenames from that folder.

Or

PHP generate page (HTML) at once with embed javascript which has array of filenames.

In both situation PHP can test file date and time to sort filenames in array.